# Does a property need to be explicitly initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

Does a property need to be explicitly initialized like so:

```
public DeviceSettings ds{ get; private set; } = new DeviceSettings();
```

**Or is it OK to keep it this way?**

```
public class MyDevice
{
    public MyDevice(string serial, int patientid)
    {

    }

    public DeviceSettings ds{ get; private set; } //no initialization needed?
}
```

Comment: @Sinatr `private` is not `readonly`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties don't need to be initialized at the time you create a new instance of your class. *That depends mostly of your business logic*.

*Property Initializers* can help you when you want to initialize your property with a default value,eg:

```
private DateTime CreateOn { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Which is translated to something like this:

```
private readonly createOn= DateTime.UtcNow;
public DateTime CreateOn 
{ 
   get
     {
        return createOn;
     } 
}
```

That is a property that is going to remain immutable after its initialization.

As @ScottChamberlain pointed out in his answer, you can initialize an [auto-implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) in the constructor of your class. That is a good place to initialize your property if this depends of an external value that is passed as parameter to the constructor, eg:

```
public class Product
{
  private PriceCalculator Calculator {get;set;}
  public decimal Price{get {return Calculator.GetPrice();}}

  public Product(int factor)
  {
    Calculator=new PriceCalculator(factor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first example `ds` is set to a new instance of `DeviceSettings`, in your 2nd example `ds` is set to `default(DeviceSettings)` which if that type is a class will be `null`.

If you wish to do it the 2nd way and your type is a class you will need to add the assignment in the constructor

```
public class MyDevice
{
    public MyDevice(string serial, int patientid)
    {
        ds = new DeviceSettings();
    }

    public DeviceSettings ds{ get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public DeviceSettings ds{ get; private set; } = new DeviceSettings();
```

That syntax was introduced only in C# 6.0. So it's completely fine do not initialize it. In that case, it will get default value (depends on DeviceSettings, is it value or reference type)

Answer (score 1):

No initialization are needed for instantiate your class.

If you're going to use property, you need to initialize it to have a correct value (it will mainly be null, because null is default value in many cases, except if your redefine it or use a struct). You can do it with C#6 syntaxic sugar as your first example, or in constructor.

Comment: property initialization not needed. It will be initialized with default value